# PHP JQUERY AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm in a bit of a blunder.

I am trying to POST data from a form using AJAX, but the data doesn't post at all.

NOTE: I have 3 files [Home.php, Post_Idea.php, Insert_Post.php]

Home.php loads in post_idea.php VIA AJAX.
I keep this AJAX code in Home.php:

```
            $("form").submit(function () {
                var title = $('#title').val();
                var body = $('#body').val();
                alert(title + " " + " " + body);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "insert_post.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {title: title, body: body},
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Insert_Post.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("include/database.php");

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
$img = "cancer_resarch_.jpg";
$votes = 0;

$stm2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (user_id, post_title, post_img, post_body, post_votes) VALUES (:user_id ,:title, :body, :img, :votes)");
$stm2->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$stm2->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stm2->bindParam(':body', $body);
$stm2->bindParam(':img', $img);
$stm2->bindParam(':votes', $votes);
$stm2->execute();
```

The problem is, this code does NOT post at all, yet the alert works and I just get this from Google Chromes Console:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHt4v.png)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This error arises because the php file is trying to execute a statement with undefined values.

Comment: Solved.
Google Chrome derped and made it this that the session was over....

Comment: Don't forget to call `event.preventDefault()` to stop the normal form submission.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error, the problem seems to be in the server side code.
I would recommend turning on the error reporting in your php script by adding this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

then to test the script I recommend using an app such as [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) for chrome and try to send the correct data.

Then you should see the error on the PHP script and on which line the error is in the body tab of postman.